# How to compile Python with all externals under Windows?

Tags: python

When I compiled Python using `PCBuild\build.bat` I discovered that several Python external projects like ssl, bz2, ... were not compiled because the compiler did not find them.

I did run the `Tools\Buildbot\external.bat` and it did download them inside `\Tools\` but it looks that the build is not looking for them in this location and the `PCBuild\readme.txt` does not provide the proper info regarding this.

In case it does matter, I do use VS2008 and VS2010 on this system.

Example:

```
Build log was saved at "file://C:\dev\os\py3k\PCbuild\Win32-temp-Release\_tkinter\BuildLog.htm"     
_tkinter - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)                                                                 
Build started: Project: bz2, Configuration: Release|Win32                                           
Compiling...                                                                                        
bz2module.c                                                                                         
..\Modules\bz2module.c(12) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bzlib.h': No such file or
 directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tools\buildbot\external.bat` must be run from py3k root, not from `Tools\buildbot\` subdir as you did. Also to build release version of python with Tkinter support you have to edit or copy Tools\buildbot\external.bat to remove DEBUG=1 so it can build tclXY.dll/tkXY.dll (without -g suffix).

Comment: Thanks, I filed a bug and patch for this issue at http://bugs.python.org/issue9822